# Vendendo e Controlando estoque (Python)

Tags: python

Fala aí rapeize.
Como faço pra pessoa que está usando o programa inserir os dados de entrada que irão a um dicionário pré cadastrado? Também, ela poder atualizar os dados do estoque, e automaticamente descontar quando a venda é efetuada. Tive pouquíssimas aulas no Python, e surgiu esse trabalho pra fazer. Não quero necessariamente o código pronto, mas sim como eu possa fazer.
Segue o que eu consegui fazer até agora:
https://pastebin.com/N2bQ7pCq

Answer (score 0):

Como resolver esse problema, após escolher o item 6:

- Listar os produtos, com um indice;
- Pedir para o usuário escolher um numero do indice para alterar;
- Conferir se o id escolhido é menor que len(escolha) ... se sim, entao a opçao existe;
- Rolar pelo dict() usando o método enumerate() para conseguir o indice e a key do dict();
- Se o id a alterar == indice do dict() : input('novo valor'); input('nova quanti')
- estoque[key] = [nova_quant, novo_valor]

```py
    def listar():
    print(f'{"Index":<8} {"Produto ":<9}{"":-<20} {"Quantidade":<12} {"Valor"}')
    index = 0
    for key, value in estoque.items():
        print(f'{index:<8} {key:<9}{"":-<20}{"":<3} {value[0]:<9} {value[1]}')
        index += 1
    id_list = []

    def conferir(numero_id):
        for ind, val in enumerate(estoque):
            id_list.append(ind)
        if numero_id in id_list : return True
        else : return

    def editar(id_alterar):
        for indice, nome in enumerate(estoque):
            if indice == id_alterar:
                n_valor = float(input('Digite o novo valor para o produto: '))
                n_quant = int(input('Digite a nova quantidade para o produto: '))
                estoque[nome] = [n_quant, n_valor]
```

```py
    elif opcao == 6:
    listar()
    alteracao = int(input('Digite o número do do id do produto que deseja alterar: '))
    conf = conferir(alteracao)
    if conf:
        editar(alteracao)
```